# How to build SDL2 with a Makefile for Windows and Android

Tags: c, ubuntu, makefile, sdl-2, mingw-w64

I have the following Makefile which builds for Linux:

```
CC := gcc
FLAGS := `sdl2-config --libs --cflags` -ggdb3 -O0 --std=c99 -lSDL2_image -lm -Wall
HDRS := $(wildcard src/c/*.h) 
SRCS := $(wildcard src/c/*.c)
OBJS := $(SRCS:src/c/%.c=tmp/%.o)
EXEC := out/PrehistoricWorld
#---------------------------------------------------------- test
FLAGS_TEST    := $(FLAGS)
SRCS_TEST     := $(wildcard test/c/*.c)
OBJS_TEST     := $(filter-out tmp/main.o, $(OBJS)) $(SRCS_TEST:test/c/%.c=tmp/%.o)
EXEC_TEST     := out/test

.SUFFIXES:
#---------------------------------------------------------- Targets

.PHONY: all

all: $(EXEC)

$(EXEC): $(OBJS) $(HDRS) Makefile
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(FLAGS) && echo "EXEC [OK]  $@"

# --------------------------------------------------------------

.PHONY: test

test: $(EXEC_TEST)

$(EXEC_TEST): $(OBJS_TEST)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJS_TEST) $(FLAGS_TEST) && echo "EXEC_TEST [OK] $@"

# --------------------------------------------------------------

tmp/%.o: src/c/%.c
    @$(CC) $(FLAGS) -c $< -o $@ && echo "tmp/%.o: src/c/%.c [OK]  $@"

tmp/%.o: test/c/%.c
    @$(CC) $(FLAGS_TEST) -c $< -o $@ && echo "tmp/%.o: test/c/%.c [OK]  $@"

.PHONY: clean, clear

clean clear:
    @rm -f out/* && echo "[CL]  out/"
    @rm -f tmp/* && echo "[CL]  tmp/"
```

It is using GCC and SDL2 and SDL2_image libs.

1. How to build my app for Windows using Makefile/Cmake - and how to setup/install the required dependencies in my host OS - Ubuntu 18.0.4 for that task?
2. How to build my app for Android using Makefile/Cmake - and how to setup/install the required dependencies in my host OS - Ubuntu 18.0.4 for that task?

EDIT:

1: I found a way to setup/install the required dependencies following the instructions listed on this website: 
[USING PRECOMPILED MINGW BINARIES FOR CROSS COMPILING AN SDL2 APPLICATION](https://crankydev.wordpress.com/2016/11/05/using-precompiled-mingw-binaries-for-cross-compiling-an-sdl2-application/)

I also managed to build with Makefile for windows platform, here is my Makefile.win:

```
CC := x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
FLAGS := -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -ggdb3 -O0 --std=c99 -lSDL2_image -lm  -Wall
HDRS := $(wildcard src/c/*.h) 
SRCS := $(wildcard src/c/*.c)
OBJS := $(SRCS:src/c/%.c=tmp/%.o)
EXEC := out/PrehistoricWorld
#---------------------------------------------------------- test
FLAGS_TEST    := $(FLAGS)
SRCS_TEST     := $(wildcard test/c/*.c)
OBJS_TEST     := $(filter-out tmp/main.o, $(OBJS)) $(SRCS_TEST:test/c/%.c=tmp/%.o)
EXEC_TEST     := out/test

.SUFFIXES:
#---------------------------------------------------------- Targets

.PHONY: all

all: $(EXEC)

$(EXEC): $(OBJS) $(HDRS) Makefile
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(FLAGS) && echo "EXEC [OK]  $@"

# --------------------------------------------------------------

.PHONY: test

test: $(EXEC_TEST)

$(EXEC_TEST): $(OBJS_TEST)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJS_TEST) $(FLAGS_TEST) && echo "EXEC_TEST [OK] $@"

# --------------------------------------------------------------

tmp/%.o: src/c/%.c
    @$(CC) $(FLAGS) -c $< -o $@ && echo "tmp/%.o: src/c/%.c [OK]  $@"

tmp/%.o: test/c/%.c
    @$(CC) $(FLAGS_TEST) -c $< -o $@ && echo "tmp/%.o: test/c/%.c [OK]  $@"

.PHONY: clean, clear

clean clear:
    @rm -f out/* && echo "[CL]  out/"
    @rm -f tmp/* && echo "[CL]  tmp/"
```

2. How to build my app for Android?

Comment: Do you assume that SDL will abstract everthing sufficiently to hide the non-trivial differences between windows and Android? I think that is not what they promise. On the other hand it is an impressive project, good luck.

Comment: SDL2 comes with `docs/README-android.md` (or something similar). Did you read it?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes I did, the setup process for android is tedious. The question is more about building for android with Makefile/Cmake, although a complete guide including the dependencies would be nice, especially if anyone already done it before. If I'll figure out the answer by myself I'll post it here.

Comment: I've done it a few years ago, but the build system SDL uses for Android was changed since then. I'd say since it's so tedious with a premade makefile, doing it with a custom makefile would probably be even worse.